# problem with dice

Tags: probability

Let X be the number of tosses of a dice to obtain the first even number.

and Y the number of tosses of the same dice to obtain the first number >3.

Both X and Y are geometric random variable with mean equals to 2.

I have to determine $P(X=Y)$

$$P(X=Y)=P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} (X=Y=k))=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X=Y=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X=k)*P(Y=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{2}* \frac{1}{2}^{k-1}*\frac{1}{2}* \frac{1}{2}^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4}^{k}=\frac{1}{3}$$
Is it wright?

In the suggested solution the probabilities in the summation are $\frac{1}{3}$. Why?

Comment: Both $X, Y$ are referring to the same dice, so you cannot claim that they are independent. You need to consider them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint, think about how you might end up with $X=Y=3$.

The first two rolls must both be 1 or 3, and the third roll must be 4 or 6.

Generalize....

Comment: Can you explain with other words? 1/3 for the last roll (I agree with you about 4 or 6) and the precedent rolls should have the complementary probability, isn't it?

Comment: The preceding rolls each must be Not Even AND Not Greater than 3, in order that neither X or Y assumes a lower value. Which is to say, either 1 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X=Y)=P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} (X=Y=k))=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X=Y=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{3}* \frac{2}{3}^{k-1}$$
because the probability that $X=Y=k$ is that at the last rolling  I have an even and >3  face (only 4 and 6 can fit this and $p=1/3$) and before this the complementary event for $k-1$ times  , with probability $2/3$.
can it be wright?

But in the solution there $1/3^{k-1}$...

Comment: Put braces around $\frac{2}{3}$, which should have been $1/3$, and maybe start at $k=0$. $\sum_{k=0}^{\inf} (1/3)^k = 3/2$. The fixed 1/3 still needs to be multiplied, so end up at 1/2

Answer (score 0):

Fix your own answer to: 
$\frac{1}{3}* \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{3})^{k-1}$

Where $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{3})^{k} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{3}{2}$

This corresponds to Ned's answer, $k$ rolls 1 or 3, and a final roll 4 or 6.